# panel/bar run conky

Tags: conky, i3-wm

I wanna run a conky in my i3 status bar. Works well with the conkyi3.sh script as status_command:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "{\"version\":1}"
echo "[[]"
exec conky -c $HOME/.conkyrc
```

and here is my conky:

```
out_to_x no
out_to_console yes
own_window no
short_units yes
update_interval 1
background no
total_run_times 0
short_units yes
use_spacer left
override_utf8_locale no
cpu_avg_samples 2

TEXT
,[

# Kernel:
{"full_text":"","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${kernel}","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\

# ip (every 10 minutes)
{"full_text":"","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${exec wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/[^[:digit:]|.]//g'} ","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false,"separator_block_width":0},\

#Finds current volume. May need modified depending on your setup"
{"full_text":"${if_match "${exec pactl list sinks | grep "Mute:" | cut -d " " -f2}"=="yes"}","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"- ","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false,"separator_block_width":0},\
{"full_text":"${else}"},\
{"full_text":"${if_match "${exec pactl list sinks | grep "Mute:" | cut -d " " -f2}"=="no"}","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${exec amixer get Master |grep % |awk '{print $5}'|sed 's/[^0-9\%]//g' | head -n 1} ","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false,"separator_block_width":0},\
{"full_text":"${endif}${endif}"},\

# Date:
{"full_text":"","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${time %m/%d/%Y}","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\

# Time:
{"full_text":"","color":"\#0048ff","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${time %r}","color":"\#f9f9f9","separator":false},\

#check for updates
{"full_text":"${if_match ${exec checkupdates | wc -l}>0} ${exec checkupdates | wc -l}","color":"\#66ff66","separator":false,"separator_block_width":6},\
{"full_text":"${endif}"}\
]
```

it's fantastic, isn't it?

Yeah, but I have the problem that i can't see the time update every second, because the ip crawler and update checker takes too long. How can I fix my problem?
Maybe seperating them into other configs? but how to load them then?

Please help me! I wanna see the real time and don't want to loose my features.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting into several conky processes might do the trick.
You can run multiple conky sessions like that:

Start a first process:

```
conky -c /path/to/config
```

and then a second session like that:

```
conky -c /path/to/other/conky/config
```

Comment: And how to change my conkyi3.sh to do this?